# Аналог или Альтернатива шрифта a_campus

Tags: вёрстка, шрифты

Добрый день всем, помогите найти альтернативу для шрифта a_campus, делаю страничку с использованием данного шрифта а он не хочет конвертироваться в форматы woff и woff2, может знает кто аналог этого шрифта для кирилицы?